# Azure functions runtime unable to start

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Trying to deploy azure function to azure.
Getting this error:

```
 The function runtime is unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 
'Endpoint=sb://servicebusnamespace001968.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]' is missing or empty.
```

What is the proper way to specify the connection string for azure deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no sure, but maybe you forget to add the `AzureWebJobsStorage`.

[image]

Is this what you want?

[image]

[image]

And don't forget to save the edit.